# Car rental in California with no credit history

Tags: usa, car-rentals, payment-cards, california, lgb

- I do not have a credit card
- I'm under 25 but older than 21
- I do not have a credit history

I'm traveling to LGB airport and want to rent a car. They say there's no way to do that without a major credit card or debit card + credit history (Hertz, Enterprise, Avis, etc.)

I have my insurance and I can make a safe deposit if required. I also have friends who are not traveling with me but have a credit card and are willing to help, but Hertz said you cannot do that.

Is there any way to rent a car in my situation?
I'm a little scared about renting a car on craigslist.

Comment: What are you wanting to do with this car? Can you do it some other way? Also can you simply get a credit card? Unless you have a horrible credit history, or literally none (not even a bank account) you should be able to get a card in a month or two.

Comment: @DJClayworth Well, I want to drive this car. Of course I can use public transportation, but won't be very convinient. They refused to give me a credit card recently and I'm leaving soon so no extra month.

Comment: What about a prepaid credit card? I guess the renting companies only require a certain amount they are able to deduct from your amex/visa/mastercard?

Comment: Prepaid cards are prohibited as far as I know.

Comment: Have you considered the obvious option of simply applying for a credit card?

Answer (score 6):

Some car rental companies allow renting with debit cards, provided you have a return ticket and sufficient amount on your bank account for a deposit. I know for a fact that major car rental companies in California (Hertz, National) allow this.

Not having a credit card *and* being under 25 may be a bad combination though....

Comment: How does being under 25 matter in this case?

Comment: Typically in the US there is a large surcharge for renting a car when you are under 25, in a lot cases it is more than the rental fee

Answer (score 2):

This is very hard to do, they all need a credit card, why not get your friend to rent the car, with you an added driver on the car, then you can drive the car,

Try this

Comment: My friend must be present in order to do that. but it's a different city.